# How to properly use makeObjectsPerformSelector: Getting error unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, arrays, selector

Let me start off by saying I am new to Objective C.

I am getting the error 
`atusMenuApp[24288:303] -[__NSCFConstantString createListItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100002450`

Here is my code:

```
selector = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"nvda", @"aapl", @"goog", nil];
[selector makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(createListItem:) withObject:self];

- (void)createListItem:(NSString *)title {
//do some stuff
}
```

Now I have done plenty of looking around and it seems like the biggest reason for this issue is the addition of or lack of the `:`however I do believe I properly have that in place. Maybe I do not understand the use of `makeObjectsPerformSelector` very well as after look up the doc on it I found:

`Sends to each object in the array the message identified by a given selector, starting with the first object and continuing through the array to the last object.`

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Only if you <s>read the documentation</s> (or thought a bit about why a method is named this way and not that), or even made the effort trying to understand the error message...]

The `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` method of `NSArray` does what it suggests it does: it makes ***the objects of the array*** perform the selector, that can have an optional argument. So

```
[selector makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(createListItem:) withObject:self];
```

will send the `createListItem:` message to ***every single `NSString` object*** in the `selector` array and pass in `self` as its argument. ***It won't perform the selector on `self` passing in the object.*** I. e., what you have is equivalent to

```
for (NSString *obj in selector) {
    [obj createListItem:self];
}
```

Obviously, instead of this, you want the following:

```
for (NSString *obj in selector) {
    [self createListItem:obj];
}
```

You don't even need that nasty method for this. A nice fast enumeration `for` loop will do it.

Comment: +1. You saw that the asker reversed the arguments by examining the argument the method takes and the contents of the array. I didn't look deep enough, obviously, so I knew why they were getting the exception but failed to understand why they thought what they did would work. :)

Comment: @Metabble Thank you. This was so irresistibly obvious that I felt an urge to answer :P

Comment: If you hadn't answered, they'd probably end up with ten answers saying `NSString` doesn't implement `createListItem` and they'd end up confused. xD

Comment: yes, see thats why I was confused from the documentation.  It seemed as though I was running the identified method in the object however from all the looking around I did on the interent it seemed that people were using how I wanted to. Thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 1):

First you make an array of `NSString`s. Then, you send them all the message `createListItem`. That's all fine and dandy, but `NSString` doesn't have any method called `createListItem`; just because you've defined an instance method called `createListItem` doesn't mean every instance of every class can use it. Only the class who's implementation file has the definition will be able to handle the message. For instance, I can't make a list of `Car` instances, then define the method `fly` in another class called `Helicopter`'s implementation and expect to be able to call `fly` on an instance of `Car`; only `Helicopter` can use it. I recommend you read a good book on Objective-C and further familiarize yourself with classes, instances and instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the method.

It will call the method `createListItem:` with argument `self` over every object of the `NSArray`.

So the resulting call would be something like:

```
[@"nvda" createListItem:self];
...
```

Clearly that method doesn't exist for a `NSString` and there goes your exception.

If you need to apply a method of `self` to every object inside your array, simply loop through it.